Issue with ABS() function - Looker Studio
In my Looker Studio report, I created the field using ABS() function, based on another field:
The source field for ABS() function as follows:
My issue is that the result given by the field with ABS() is incorrect:
Is there any solution to this problem, to make the ABS field actually give the absolute value from another field?
